# githubの中にあるソースから特定のimport文を含むリポジトリを検索する

Tags: python, github

パッケージがどのように使われているかを調べるために
githubで特定のimport文を含むPythonのソースファイルが入ったリポジトリを検索したいです。
どうすれば検索できるでしょうか。
Pythonでソースを組まずにWebブラウザで検索できることが一番望ましいですが、ソースを組む必要があればその方法を教えてください。
例) import random で検索すると import random を含んだソースファイルが入ったリポジトリを検索する。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

一番簡単なのは、GitHub サイト上で "random" でコード検索し、言語を Python に絞ることでしょう。[このような感じです。](https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=random&type=Code)

残念なことに、GitHub のサイト上ではダブルクォーテーションを使って全体一致させるような検索はできません。したがって "import random" と連続した並びのみを取り出すような検索はできません。このことは GitHub ヘルプの ["Searching code"](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/) に暗に書かれています。

> You can't use the following wildcard characters as part of your search query: `` . , : ; / \ ` ' " = * ! ? # $ & + ^ | ~ < > ( ) { } [ ] ``. The search will simply ignore these symbols.

また、同じヘルプに書かれているように、GitHub にあるリポジトリ全体から検索されているわけではないのでご注意ください。

他の方法として、Google 検索で

```
"import random" site:https://github.com
```

のように検索することもできます。[このような感じです。](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22import%20random%22%20site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com)

Comment: ありがとうございます。まさに探していた情報でした。